# .Net calulations optimization with sql server db access

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Looking for best approach to optimize the calculations below.

It retrieves a list of dates in the database and then for each date
Takes the portfolio, calculate the performance contribution of each asset in the portfolio by retrieving weight and prices in the database.

Aside building a cache to reduce number of db access and adding relevant indexes in the database. Is there something I can do to reduce significantly the time it takes to perform the calculations ? Is there components in the framework helping to work in an efficient manner ?

Currently this takes about 200s to complete with professional class DB (average access time between 1ms and 2ms)

```
public static void CalculatePerformance(string portfolioID)
        {
            using (var db = new MarketDataContext())
            {
                var sbTest = new StringBuilder();
                var nav = 100m;
                var dates = db.cPortfolios.Where(t => t.PortfolioID == portfolioID).Select(t => t.PositionDate).Distinct().OrderBy(t => t).ToArray();
                var prevDate = (DateTime)dates[0];
                sbTest.AppendLine(prevDate.ToString("d") + "," + nav);
                for (int i = 1; i < dates.Length; i++)
                {
                    var date = (DateTime)dates[i];
                    var totalCTR = 0m;
                    var portfolio = db.cPortfolios.Where(t => t.PositionDate == date && t.PortfolioID == portfolioID).Select(t => t);
                    foreach (var cPortfolio in portfolio)
                    {
                        var ret = (MarketPrices.GetPrice(cPortfolio.Ticker, date) / MarketPrices.GetPrice(cPortfolio.Ticker, prevDate) - 1);
                        var ctr = (cPortfolio.Exposure ?? 0m) * (ret ?? 0m);
                        totalCTR += ctr;
                    }
                    nav = nav * (1 + totalCTR/100);
                    sbTest.AppendLine(date.ToString("d") + "," + nav);
                    prevDate = date;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that you try to do this on the client in the first place. Second problem, that you use a loop to execute N queries instead of one query that returns all of the data you want in one execution. What are you trying to do in the first place? Explain the business case, because it looks like you only need one SQL query with a GROUP By on dates. You *can* calculate running totals with SQL too. Getting all ticker prices for a portfolio by date is just a JOIN between Portfoliso and MarketPrice

Comment: From Sergey: Have you tried making these calculations on the server side?

Comment: Get all the data before you enter any loops and filter as you go, much quicker than executing many queries. If this can be ecapsulated into a stored proc, even better.

Comment: @DaveBecker that's not exactly it. This looks like a single join and running total, grouped by date. The only data that needs to get to the client are the finished results by date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, my bad, misinterpreted: "...that you use a loop to execute N queries instead of one query that returns all of the data you want in one execution". Removed you name from my comment. Apologies.

Comment: @DaveBecker On the other hand, if `MarketPrices` isn't a database call, the OP may have to get the ticker prices for all dates first and store them to the database.

Comment: @DaveBecker or ... em, it seems the code *reloads* the portfolio inside the loop? It seems you are right that the OP should load the portfolio data at least instead of trying to reload the same data for each day. Still the correct SQL query would return the final results in the time it took to load the positions only

Comment: @aam are you trying to calculate a portfolio's performance? Please post your tables' schema. You can do all that in SQL. You can get a previous value with LAG() so the ratio becomes `Price/LAG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER by PositionDate)`. You can calculate a running total with `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticket ORDER by PositionDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`

Comment: MarketPrices is a db call. The inner loop is loading the portfolio for the main loop current date. from what I understand you say I can't do the calculation on the client side with a comparable performance ? For code architecture/maintainability I wanted to have this on the client in C#. I changed the code to load the porfolios grouped by date instead of  calling them one by one in the code but it did not improve much the time. Down to 195s from 206s. Only db call in the loop are the GetPrice. Maybe I can build a dictionnary cache.

Comment: @aam why??? A single SQL query can return the final results. What is the *actual* business problem you want to solve? Why load unnecessary data on the client? Besides, you don't need caching or dictionaries. Your loop hits the *same* portfolio entries you loaded outside the loop. Just load the data you want once , don't hit the database inside a loop.

Comment: because inside GetPrice you can retrieve the prices from different sources, different databases, with different options. Not so easy in SQL.

Comment: @aam furthermore, you *can* perform aggregations with LINQ. You shouldn't need the loop at all for your calculations. The actual problem is `MarketPrices.GetPrice` which prevents you from joining with the other entities, or applying aggregate operations

Comment: @aam that will only work for a small range of instruments and dates. It won't scale when you need to calculate eg monthly portfolio returns for all customers, or many dates for a single customer. At least, it should be modified to load a *range* of dates, not a single one. Instead of performing 300 calls to return 1 row each time, make 1 call that returns 300 rows

Comment: @aam PS, also note that the loop loads each price *twice*. Once for the current date, and once for the *next*. You end up executing 600 queries to get 300 prices. Things get much worse when calling external services, as they are typically far slower than an internal database

Comment: the absolute killer is in fact the text index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MarketPrices.GetPrice(cPortfolio.Ticker, date)` is killing the performance because Id ticker is text and as to be changed to int => Reduce time by 70%.
Then moving these calls to a stored function server side makes the results instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you're using a Linq in order to make a Join from Date of Portefolio to MarketPlace of Ticker of the related Portefolio and then applying a function to the later. I see two way to improve your solution.

**Number 1 : Going for a SQL solution.** To my mind redesigning a proper JOIN query without Linq is the most efficient way to do it.

**Number 2 : Going for a .NET solution.** You may also want to make this JOIN as a .NET table in order to query it and use it.

Not knowing your SQL architecture nor your .NET architecture I can't help you with examples.